# .NET Core 3.0.100 not working with Blazor

Tags: .net-core, blazor

I just downloaded the .NET Core 3.0.100-preview-010184 (the lastest .NET Core so far). I wanted to generate a Blazor project to try it. So I did what's written [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=netcore-cli):

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::0.8.0-preview-19104-04
```

And then:

```
dotnet new blazor -o Blazor.App
cd Blazor.App
dotnet run
```

But instead of running, I'm getting this error:

> Unable to generate deps.json, it may have been already generated.  You can specify the "-d" option before the tool name for diagnostic output (for example, "dotnet -d ": C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview-010184\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\GenerateDeps\GenerateDeps.proj

I tried running it with and without administrator privileges.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a know issue, mentioned in the [release blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-0-8-0-experimental-release-now-available/#known-issues).

"Unable to generate deps.json, it may have been already generated.": You may see this error when running a standalone Blazor app and you haven't yet restored packages for any .NET Core apps. To workaround this issue create any .NET Core app (ex dotnet new console) and then rerun the Blazor app.

All you need to do is run the following command

```
dotnet new console
```

This will generate a new console app. You can then delete it and you should then be able to run your blazor app.